# How to solve this integral relating to time taken on an ellipse?

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

When I attempt to solve this integral using Wolfram Alpha, it says that no integral exists in standard mathematical form. Why is it so? It is possible to integrate this?

[image: Indefinite integral giving time]

The bottom limit is 0 and the upper limit is 23260.

Comment: Most functions do not have closed form integral expressions.  You can of course do a numerical integration if you specify limits on your integral.

Comment: @Michael I added my limits in my edit. What is the best method to carry out a numerical integration.

Comment: Wolfram alpha gives me an answer of 48.2391. Go to the wolfram alpha site and enter this into the input window: int ((1-26*(x-900)/(125*sqrt(5*10^8 - (x-900)^2)))^2/(2*9.81*(4600+sqrt(2.08^2/100*(5*10^8-(x-900)^2)))))^(1/2), x=0..23260

Comment: The wolfram alpha site is here: https://www.wolframalpha.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Risch algorithm provides a formal way to check whether an integral is elementarily solvable. It would return a negative result for this integral, in spite of its (usually) long running time.

However, there is a simpler, if less rigorous, way to see this: the preponderance of square-rooted terms that cannot be simplified, because they are added to other terms with different square roots, or none at all. Even the simpler
$$\int\sqrt{\frac1{\sqrt x+1}}\,dx$$
is not elementarily solvable.